# What is the maximum homogeneous nucleation rate of supercooled liquid quartz?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, bond

I read in [College Physics, Volume 1](https://books.google.ca/books?id=DuzkAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA236&lpg=PA236&dq=supercooled%20liquid%20quartz&source=bl&ots=nAn9j5Aeub&sig=XMEDOY4wOujNYG-zknYLlxYK6bU&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=supercooled%20liquid%20quartz&f=false) (by John Oren Reed, Karl Eugen Guther) that fused quartz is just supercooled liquid quartz. Is it really supercooled liquid quartz?

As liquid quartz is cooled below its melting point, does it eventually get to a temperature where achieves such a high homogeneous nucleation rate that it can't be supercooled any further.

Is it the case that the homogeneous nucleation rate only goes up to a rate that's still low enough to avoid nucleation at the macroscopic level with slow cooling and then starts going down again as a result of bonds not getting broken and reformed as often due to the lower temperature?